# Not able to access angular html from my normal html website

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I have simple HTML website.

I want to redirect to angular website on click of button in html website.

I have hosted HTML website and Angular build also on same server Hostinger.

[This is the simple HTML button from which I want to redirect to angular project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLHAX.png)

```
 <header class="manpower_inquiry">
        <div class="manpower_inquiry__text-box">
            <h1 class="heading-primary">
                <span class="heading--top">manpower supply</span>
                <br/>
                <!-- <span class="heading-primary--sub--service">Leading Retail security providers
                </span> -->
            </h1>

            <a href="../inquiry/MAN_P/index.html" class="btn btn--white btn--animated">Inquiry</a>
        </div>
  </header>
```

[This is the Angular build on Hostinger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUNrG.png)

[The html page from which I'm redirecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGHhr.png)

[The error I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UGUd.png)

[This is my Angular project routing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCvQn.png)

Please help me to resolve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you deploying your angular application in a subfolder change your base path in the angular HTML page to

```
<base href="./">
```

I fetched a similar situation I fixed in this way.